# jQuery Table Search filter on a PHP generated table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I have a MySQL table with less than a thousand rows and it's fetched by a PHP script. I would like to be able to sort the `tbody` by ASC or DESC order when clicking a link and still be able to use the search bar like in the [**this demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/aYH6r/). However when I try to incorporate the coding in my PHP generated table, my search bar doesn't filter. I must be doing something wrong.

Here's my PHP script:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>".$row['fruits']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['colors']."</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
mysql_close();
```

If possible I'd like to have some hint, snippet or even examples would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**PHP Solutions :**

```
    <?php
    $sort_name = "id";
    $sort_type = "asc";

    if($_GET['sort'] == "fruits")
       $sort_name = "fruits_column_name";
    else if($_GET['sort'] == "colors")
       $sort_name = "colors_column_name";
    if($_GET['sort_type'] == "desc")
       $sort_type = "desc";

    $sql = "SELECT * from mytable where some conditions ORDERBY " . $sort_name . " " . $sort_type;
    //run your query;



    //later in ur HTML
    <tr>
        <th><a href="?sort=fruits&sort_type=<?= ($sort_name=='fruits' && $sort_type=='asc')?'desc':'asc' ?>">Fruits</a></th>
        <th><a href="?sort=colors&sort_type=<?= ($sort_name=='colors' && $sort_type=='asc')?'desc':'asc' ?>">Colors</a></th>
    </tr>
```

**JQuery Solution:**

> http://jsfiddle.net/QxNmJ/

**Javascript Library Solution:**

use this library https://datatables.net/ very handy and it will gives you everything that you are looking for.

Comment: Is there a way to not use datatables to implement these features?

Comment: I added a JQuery solution, you can check it, it's simple and you can alter it easily. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I tryed a little around with both JSFiddle versions and found a working Solution for the Search and Sort, it will also Sort the Search results.
Only downside is that the Sort will sort Uppercase bevor Lowercase.

> A B C ... Z a b c ... z

---

```
var $rows = $('#table tbody tr');
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function () {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});

function compare(a,b) {
    var val1= $(a).find('td').text();
    var val2= $(b).find('td').text();

    if (val1 < val2)
        return -1;
    if (val1 > val2)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

$('#sort').click(function(){


    $('#table').html($('#table tr').sort(compare));

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QxNmJ/3/

Greetings from Germany

---

KS_HTK